# How to create model fields in a loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a project in Django where in my '**Myapp**' I have two models in models.py. I am trying to achieve the objects of **model_1** to be the field of my **model_2**. The example of my code and what I have tried has been shown below:-

> Model_1 in models.py

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    skill_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank= False)
```

> Model_2 in models.py (What I have tried)

```
class Resources(models.Model):
      pass   
     
     for skill in Skills.objects.all():
         Resources.add_to_class(skill, models.CharField(max_length=200))
```

> the error that I am getting

```
NameError: name 'Resources' is not defined
```

Can anyone provide a better solution to my problem that can create a model_2(Resources)
that will have fields skill_1, skill_2,...,skill_3 from my model_1(Skills)

Comment: You **don't**: that would be a *horrible* idea since you would each time have to migrate if there is a new `Skill`s object.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't**: that would be a *horrible* idea since you would each time have to migrate if there is a new `Skill`s object.

Normally you construct a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) between `Resource` and `Skill`, and with the [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) you can add extra data. For example:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    # …
    pass

class Resource(models.Model):
    # …
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(
        Skill,
        through='SkillResource',
        related_name='resources'
    )
     
class SkillResource(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

For more information how to present a many-to-many relation in a relational database, see the [*associative entity* wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).